# difference between two x86 IA32 ISA instructions?

Tags: x86

I've noticed that the notation for setting a register to 0 in the x86 IA32 ISA is commonly expressed as:

```
xorl %eax, %eax
```

I'd like to know if there's a difference between this notation and

```
movl $0, %eax
```

Since both seem to be essentially doing the same thing. Is this just a matter of efficiency?

Comment: `Is this just a matter of efficiency?` Yes. Generally, xor opcode is shorter, in most cases it is faster. To get an exact answer, refer to Assembly reference for specific platform.

Comment: Mostly, but `xor` affects the flags. So if you have to preserve the flags (which is only rarely the case), you can't use it.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is just a matter of efficiency.  Intel recommends using **xorl** over **movl** because its processors recognize that the result of xor'ing a register with itself is always 0 - it does not depend on what originally was in the register [(See section 3.5.1.8)](http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/architecture-and-technology/64-ia-32-architectures-optimization-manual.html).  This makes clearing the register an independent operation with regard to other instructions and can increase instruction level parallelism and performance.  Intel doesn't promise that **Movl** has this property.

Comment: `movl` doesn't depend on the previous value either

Comment: True, but you Intel x86 processor doesn't know that.

Comment: Sure it does. When it does it's register renaming business it sees no input register, therefore no dependency. Unless it's an 8 or 16 bit `mov` of course, but this is a `movl`. However, the `xor` is still faster, since it doesn't even execute.

Comment: Strictly speaking, Intel does not specify what happens on a **movl** instruction.  I've modified my original post to reflect this.

Comment: "move 0 into the register" is also listen in 3.5.1.8 though

Comment: @harold: "Furthermore, they do not consume an issue port or an execution unit. So using zero idioms are preferable than [sic] moving 0’s into the register."

Comment: @StephenCanon yes that's a better way to describe "doesn't even execute"